# How to login to webpage via Visual Basic console application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, httprequest, html, autologin

I've been tasked at work to make our company's software auto-login to a webpage so we can send GET-requests **without webbrowser or VS form**

My company's software runs on an industrial machine so the whole thing has to be run automatically from within Visual Studio. 
So far all the answers to this topic involve some kind of browser, which is why I wanted to ask you guys:

How do I get the cookie and what do I do with it?

How do I submit UN and PW (codewise) to the j_security part of the webpage and using what parameters?

The site ends in login.jsp or j_security.jsp. We have been told to send a GET request for a cookie first and then send Username and PW via POST.

I've started programming in VB literally 2 weeks ago and would appreciate any help! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend you look up the WebBrowser control, then reformulate your question(s) based on your experience using it.

Comment: Hi thanks. I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve any kind of forms. It has to run 100% automatically, I preset the UN and PW. Currently I am sending a POST request to (url)/j_security.jsp. However I get Status:302 back.

Comment: You are aware that WinForms can be automated and hidden in order to avoid actually requiring any user input at any time, right? Because I can say from personal experience that WebBrowser is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @NathanTuggy thanks, that's good to know. the thing is, my code module is part of a much bigger piece of software and has to be as unintrusive as possible and fully automatic. Nobody will ever see or use that form. I actually managed to do it without the form using a straight-up POST-request to j_security_check

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please follow this url. it will demostrate you the auto login process

[Click here for example](http://www.i-programmer.info/projects/36-web/6302-automatic-web-page-use-with-net.html)

You might need to change Element name for UserName and Password.

Go to your Login page --> View Pages Source --> Go to username and replace it with "txtUsername" in code. same process for password.

Hope this will help.

Nishit

Comment: Hi thanks, however this isn't what I am looking for as it uses a form. I am looking to do this without a form, purely with GET / POST and if necessary a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I managed to solve it guys:

1. Simple request to login.jsp to get the session cookie
2. POST-request with UN and PW to j_security_check (using the cookie from before!)

   ```
   Public Sub GetCookie()
   Console.WriteLine("GlobalCookieContainer.Count {0}",GlobalCookieContainer.Count)

   Dim URL As String = "https://DaWebsite.com/sthg/index.jsp?enable=all"
   Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL)                                  'Create a request for the URL. 

   request.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()                                             'CookieContainer aufsetzen
   GlobalCookieContainer = request.CookieContainer                                             'Cookies aus dem Request in den globalen CookieContainer laden

   Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()                                     'Get the response.
   Console.WriteLine("resp.StatusCode ist: {0}, resp.StatusDescription ist: {1}", Int(response.StatusCode), response.StatusDescription)
   Console.WriteLine("Server {0}, Uri {1}, Method {2}, Cookies {3}", response.Server, response.ResponseUri, response.Method, response.Cookies)

   'DATA STREAM
   Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()                                     'Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
   Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)                                                  'Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
   Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()                                       'Read the content.
   'Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer.Substring(0,100))                                      'Display the content.
   reader.Close()                                                                              'Clean up the streams and the response.
   response.Close()

   Console.WriteLine("CookieContainer.Count: {0}",request.CookieContainer.Count)               'Anzahl der Cookies angeben
   Console.WriteLine()        
   Console.ReadKey()                                                                                  Call JSecurity()
   End Sub


   Private Sub JSecurity()                                                               'WebRequestPostExample.JSecurity()
   Try
       Console.WriteLine("JSecurity Anfrage")
       Console.ReadKey()

       Dim username As String = "UN"                                                    'Username
       Dim password As String = "PW"                                                'Password
       Dim URL As String = "https://DaWebsite.com/stgh/j_security_check"

       Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(URL), HttpWebRequest)
       request.CookieContainer = GlobalCookieContainer                   'Cookie wiederverwenden
       request.Method = "POST"                                                                 'Set the Method property of the request to POST.
       Dim postData As String = "j_username=" & username & "&j_password=" & password           'Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
       Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
       request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"                           ' Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.    
       request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length                                            ' Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.

       'DATA STREAM
       Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()                               ' Get the request stream.
       dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)                                    ' Write the data to the request stream.
       dataStream.Close()                                                                  ' Close the Stream object.

       'RESPONSE
       Dim resp As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()                                 ' Get the response.
       Console.WriteLine("resp.StatusCode ist: {0}, resp.StatusDescription ist: {1}", Int(resp.StatusCode), resp.StatusDescription)
       Console.WriteLine("Server {0}, Uri {1}, Method {2}, Cookies {3}", resp.Server, resp.ResponseUri, resp.Method, resp.Cookies)
       Console.ReadKey()                                                                     ' Display elements of repsonse that came from the request issued above.

       dataStream = resp.GetResponseStream()                                               ' Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
       Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)                                          ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
       Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()                               ' Read the content.
       'Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)                                               ' Display the content.

       reader.Close()                                                                      ' Clean up the streams.
       dataStream.Close()
       resp.Close()
       Console.WriteLine()    

       If Int(resp.StatusCode) = 200 Then
               LoggedIn = True
       Else
               LoggedIn = False
       End If
       Call TestConnection()

   Catch e As WebException
       Console.WriteLine("FEHLER")
       Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
       If e.Status = WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError Then
           Console.WriteLine("Status Code : {0}", CType(e.Response, HttpWebResponse).StatusCode)
           Console.WriteLine("Status Description : {0}", CType(e.Response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
           Console.WriteLine("Resonse URI: {0}", e.Response.ResponseUri)
           Console.WriteLine("IsFromCache: {0}", e.Response.IsFromCache)
           Console.WriteLine("IsMutuallyAuthenticated: {0}", e.Response.IsMutuallyAuthenticated)
           Console.WriteLine()
           Call StartLogin

       End If
   Catch e As Exception
       Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
   End Try

   End Sub
   ```